# Angualr2 Final router throws exception

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have created a simple router for my application to support a url like this
www.myhost.com/mission/myguid. I have checked the tutorials on the angular site but I don't found differences. "Normal" routes like www.myhost.com/home works fine for me.

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import {HomeComponent} from './general/home/home.component';
import {MissionComponent} from './map/mission/mission.component';

// Route config let's you map routes to components
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,        
    },
    {
        path: 'mission/:guid',
        component: MissionComponent
    },        
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/home,',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Using this I recive this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined
and
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Has anyone a idea what I do wrong?

UPDATE:
App Module:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routes';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import {HomeComponent} from './general/home/home.component';
import {MissionComponent} from './map/mission/mission.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, FormsModule, HttpModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent,
        MissionComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Main component:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

APP Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'emersy-app',
   templateUrl: "./app/app.component.html",
})

export class AppComponent { }
```

UPDATE 2:
systemjs.config.js

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        // DEMO ONLY! REAL CODE SHOULD NOT TRANSPILE IN THE BROWSER
        transpiler: 'ts',
        typescriptOptions: {
            tsconfig: true
        },
        meta: {
            'typescript': {
                "exports": "ts"
            }
        },
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',

            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',

            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'ts': 'npm:plugin-typescript@4.0.10/lib/plugin.js',
            'typescript': 'npm:typescript@2.0.2/lib/typescript.js',

        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.ts',
                defaultExtension: 'ts'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <title>Emersy</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAmRxDewohpXFhVXbRFdAnvVAS28NPRhNU&libraries=places&sensor=true"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="copyright" content="">
    <meta name="geo.region" content="">
    <meta name="geo.position" content="">
    <meta name="ICBM" content="46, 11">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets\img\favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\css\emersy.css">


    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <script src="app/map/utils/overlay.js"></script>  

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <noscript>
        <div class="msg error siterequirements">

        </div>
    </noscript>
    <emersy-app>Loading....</emersy-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does NGModule do here???

Comment: used the same thing like here https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-5/ts/plnkr.html https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html

Comment: show me @NgModule of appmodule or mainmodule or rootmodule.

Comment: add to my question

Comment: Everything looks alright. problem is not here.

Comment: can it be a problem in the systemsjs.config.js or in the index.html?

Comment: Maybe but hard to say...

Comment: adds both files

Comment: but you don't have this route defined anywhere : `mission/myguid`

Comment: try this and it will work `www.myhost.com/mission/1`

Comment: it's not this the definition of my route {
        path: 'mission/:guid',
        component: MissionComponent
    },

Comment: a one moment if I create a link like this <a routerLink="/mission/1">Heroes</a> then the route works but if I call a link  directly in the browser i recive the error.

Comment: ok changed base href to <base href="/"> looks like that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that i have used this from the angular2 tutorials:

```
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```

instead of this:

```
<base href="/">
```

Maybe is a good choice to read the manual :-)

> LIVE EXAMPLE NOTE
>
> We have to get tricky when we run the live example because the host
>   service sets the application base address dynamically. That's why we
>   replace the  with a script that writes a  tag on
>   the fly to match.
>
> ```
> <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + >'" />');/script>
> ```
>
> We should only need this trick for the live example,
>   not production code.